MONGODB - how to not take null value in left join
Hello I have a mongo code, I have write this :
db.Department.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      ParentRef: null
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Department",
      localField: "Syscode",
      foreignField: "ParentRef",
      as: "N2"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$N2",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Department",
      localField: "N2.Syscode",
      foreignField: "ParentRef",
      as: "N3"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$N3",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Department",
      localField: "N3.Syscode",
      foreignField: "ParentRef",
      as: "N4"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$N4",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "N1_Code": "$Code",
      "N1_Name": "$Name",
      "N2_Code": "$N2.Code",
      "N2_Name": "$N2.Name",
      "N3_Code": "$N3.Code",
      "N3_Name": "$N3.Name",
      "N4_Code": "$N4.Code",
      "N4_Name": "$N4.Name"
    }
  },
  
  
])

I want a code like this, this is the code I have translate in MONGODB
select N1.Code, N1.Name, N2.Code, N2.Name, N3.Code, N3.Name, N4.Code, N4.Name
from Department  as N1
LEFT JOIN Department as N2 ON N1.Syscode = N2.ParentRef  
LEFT JOIN Department as N3 ON N2.Syscode = N3.ParentRef   
LEFT JOIN Department as N4 ON N3.Syscode = N4.ParentRef   
WHERE N1.ParentRef IS NULL 

problem I have bad result, mongodb does  a join in null value how this is possible?
Exemple if N2.Syscode is null N3.Code show N1.Code and N3.Name show N1.Name
thx for help

Would be great to share the sample input document and expected result.

Are you looking for this demo?

https://mongoplayground.net/p/boIU_MbHv-8
most probably bevause some of your intermediate N2.Syscode are null after the step preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true. youll need to do a pipeline in lookup to ignore the nulls when compairing. otherwise it will give the ones where the ParentRef is null matched with the N2.Syscode = null

hi cmgchess same than Yong request not work https://mongoplayground.net/p/vVYb6kFk5eQ, look result you have N3_Code and N4_Code exist when N2_Code is not

@guillaumezac Both cmgchess and yong shun's proposals look ok to me. The result may not be "visualized" in playground since it has a 100 document per collection limitation. Can you trim down the sample data set to include a specific set of related document as a [mre] ?

In the example you provided here, there is no document with "ParentRef": NumberInt(101) so the first lookup onwards is always just empty. And in the second lookup, the same Dummy_666 just keeps looking up itself. So that needs a null check in/before the lookup. Provide a smaller example (10-20 documents) where the lookup would actually work / have a referenced Syscode.
